# Definition of knot $p$-colorability

Tags: modular-arithmetic, knot-theory

On [page 4 of this online document](http://educ.jmu.edu/~taalmala/OJUPKT/layla_thesis.pdf), *p-Colorings of Weaving Knots* by Layla Oesper the following definition is given:

Given an odd prime number p we say that the projection of a knot $K$ is $p$-colorable if every strand in the projection can be labeled using the number $0$ to $p - 1$, with at least $2$ of the labels distinct, so that at each crossing we have

$2x - y - z = 0 \mod p$,

where $x$ is the value assigned to the overstrand and $y$ and $z$ are the values assign to the understrands of the crossing.

I see that the idea is to assign a colorability number to a knot to classify it, but what is the role the ''$2$" in the equation above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of $p$-colorability was popularized by Ralph Fox as a way to explain dihedral representations of fundamental groups of knot complements to high schoolers.  Expanding this out just a little, the group $\pi_1(S^3-K)$ has a presentation known as the [Wirtinger presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_presentation), where generators correspond to meridians and relations correspond to crossings.  If the basepoint is above the diagram, a meridian generator is a straight-line path from the basepoint to an arc, then around the knot in a short meridian loop, then back, like so:

[image: Meridian generator]

A *dihedral representation* is a homomorphism $\pi_1(S^3-K)\to D_p$ with $D_p$ the dihedral group (symmetries of a regular $p$-gon) where each meridian is sent to a flip of the polygon.  Such a representation is called *nontrivial* if there are two meridians that are sent to different flips.  Since flips are involutions, we don't need to worry about orientations of meridian generators.  Every dihedral representation factors through the quotient group
$$\pi_1(S^3-K)/\langle \mu^2=1\text{ for }\mu\text{ a meridian generator}\rangle,$$
so we will work with this group instead of $\pi_1(S^3-K)$ itself.  An important consequence is that we do not need to worry about orientations in the Wirtinger relations.

The relations for the Wirtinger presentation come from loops just under crossings:

[image: Wirtinger relation (unoriented)]

Here, $ab=ca$, or $c=aba^{-1}$.  That is, "passing a generator under a crossing conjugates it by the overstrand's generator."

Recall that the dihedral group has a presentation
$$D_p=\langle \sigma,\tau\mid \sigma^n=1,\tau^2=1,\tau\sigma=\sigma^{-1}\tau\rangle,$$
where $\sigma$ is rotation of the polygon by $2\pi/p$ and $\tau$ is a flip.
Every flip of $D_p$ can be represented as $\sigma^k\tau$ for $k\in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, and we have the following conjugation rule from the relations:
$$(\sigma^x\tau)(\sigma^y\tau)(\sigma^x\tau)^{-1} = \sigma^x\tau\sigma^{y-x} = \sigma^x\sigma^{x-y}\tau=\sigma^{2x-y}\tau.$$

Thus, at a crossing with $a=\sigma^x\tau$, $b=\sigma^y\tau$, and $c=\sigma^z\tau$, there must be the relation that $\sigma^z=\sigma^{2x-y}$.  That is, that
$$z\equiv 2x-y\pmod{p}.$$

There is a version of $p$-colorability for knotted graphs, too, where like the Wirtinger presentation the relations come from loops underneath vertices in a diagram for the knotted graph.  For example, in a degree-$4$ vertex

[image: degree four vertex]

the (unoriented) relation is $abcd=1$.  With $a=\sigma^x\tau$, $b=\sigma^y\tau$, $c=\sigma^z\tau$, and $d=\sigma^w\tau$, this relation becomes $\sigma^{x-y+z-w}=1$, or
$$x-y+z-w\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$
There is a way to turn a degree-$4$ vertex into a crossing by identifying a pair of opposite edges to be the overstrand.  For example, if we want $a$ and $c$ to form the overstrand, we add in $\sigma^x\tau=\sigma^z\tau$, which is $x\equiv z\pmod {p}$.  Substituting this into the above equation, we obtain
$$2x-y-w\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$
Perhaps this shows where the $2$ comes from: the overstrand identifies the two meridians, but the "real" $p$-coloring relation is an alternating sum around the crossing.

Comment: Wow! My rudimentary group theory is not enough to follow... I was thinking that perhaps each cross over involves three arcs, and that this fact reduces the more complex problem of the entire knot to a more manageable problem of tri-colorability in each crossing. In this way, x + y + z = 0 mod3 can be expressed as 2y = x + z, because x + z = -y, but 2y = -y mod3. Therefore, the overstrand could be assigned to y, and correspond to the arithmetic mean of x and z. Any value to this?

Comment: @AnthonyF. The $2$ is not due to the $\pmod{3}$ (since it's $2$ no matter the $p$), but rather it's that going around the crossing gives the equation $x-y+x-z\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.  It's reasonable trying to turn a knot into a system of equations (even if $p$-colorability comes from some group theory).  It'd be a good exercise to try to find *all* ways of assigning a system of equations to a knot, one equation per crossing.

Comment: @AnthonyF. By the way, if you take the system of equations for $p$ coloring as a matrix then take the determinant after crossing off a row and column, you get what is called the *knot determinant*.  If a knot has a nontrivial $p$ coloring, then $p$ divides the knot determinant.  There are knots whose determinant is $1$, so these have no non-trivial $p$ colorings for any $p$.

Comment: Any chance you could expand on your comment, " it's that going around the crossing gives the equation x − y + x − z ≡ 0(modp)"?

Comment: @AnthonyF. It's reiterating the last part of my answer, where it turns out the equations for $p$-coloring are from doing an alternating sum of the incident arcs around a crossing (two of which are the same arc).  Without knowing more information about what you would like clarification about, I can't really say more than that.

Comment: "(two of which are the same arc)" = the overstrand is the same arc.

Comment: @AnthonyF. There's a certain perspective of knot diagrams where they are $4$-regular graphs embedded in the plane with some additional data: which of the two edges incident to a vertex form the overstrand.  I should say "an alternating sum of the colors associated to the incident *edges* around the crossing (two of which are for the same arc)" to be clearer.

Comment: Unbelievable clear. Thanks.